# Perl Win32::API and Pointers

Tags: c++, perl, winapi, types

I'm trying to utilize the Win32 API function DsGetSiteName() using Perl's Win32::API module. According to the Windows SDK, the function prototype for DsGetSiteName is:

```
DWORD DsGetSiteName(LPCTSTR ComputerName, LPTSTR *SiteName)
```

I successfully wrote a small C++ function using this API to get a better understanding of how it would actually work (I'm learning C++ on my own, but I digress).

Anyhow, from my understanding of the API documentation, the second parameter is supposed to be a pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to a string. In my C++ code, I wrote that as:

```
LPSTR site;
LPTSTR *psite = &site;
```

and have successfully called the API using the psite pointer.

Now my question is, is there a way to do the same using Perl's Win32::API? I've tried the following Perl code:

```
my $site = " " x 256;
my $computer = "devwin7";

my $DsFunc = Win32::API->new("netapi32","DWORD DsGetSiteNameA(LPCTSTR computer, LPTSTR site)");
my $DsResult = $DsFunc->Call($computer, $site);
print $site;
```

and the result of the call in $DsResult is zero (meaning success), but the data in $site is not what I want, it looks to be a mixture of ASCII and non-printable characters.

Could the $site variable be holding the pointer address of the allocated string? And if so, is there a way using Win32::API to dereference that address to get at the string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Win32::API can't handle `char**`. You'll need to extract the string yourself.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use Encode     qw( encode decode );
use Win32::API qw( );

use constant {
   NO_ERROR                => 0,
   ERROR_NO_SITENAME       => 1919,
   ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY => 8,
};

use constant PTR_SIZE => $Config{ptrsize};

use constant PTR_FORMAT =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'L'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

use constant PTR_WIN32API_TYPE =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'N'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

# Inefficient. Needs a C implementation.
sub decode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $sW = '';
   for (;;) {
      my $chW = unpack('P2', pack(PTR_FORMAT, $ptr));
      last if $chW eq "\0\0";
      $sW .= $chW;
      $ptr += 2;
   }

   return decode('UTF-16le', $sW);   
}


sub NetApiBufferFree {
   my ($Buffer) = @_;

   state $NetApiBufferFree = Win32::API->new('netapi32.dll', 'NetApiBufferFree', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, 'N')
      or die($^E);

   $NetApiBufferFree->Call($Buffer);
}


sub DsGetSiteName {
   my ($ComputerName) = @_;

   state $DsGetSiteName = Win32::API->new('netapi32.dll', 'DsGetSiteNameW', 'PP', 'N')
      or die($^E);

   my $packed_ComputerName = encode('UTF-16le', $ComputerName."\0");
   my $packed_SiteName_buf_ptr = pack(PTR_FORMAT, 0);

   $^E = $DsGetSiteName->Call($packed_ComputerName, $packed_SiteName_buf_ptr)
      and return undef;

   my $SiteName_buf_ptr = unpack(PTR_FORMAT, $packed_SiteName_buf_ptr);

   my $SiteName = decode_LPCWSTR($SiteName_buf_ptr);

   NetApiBufferFree($SiteName_buf_ptr);

   return $SiteName;
}


{
    my $computer_name = 'devwin7';

    my ($site_name) = DsGetSiteName($computer_name)
       or die("DsGetSiteName: $^E\n");

    say $site_name;
}
```

All but `decode_LPCWSTR` is untested.

I used the WIDE interface instead of the ANSI interface. Using the ANSI interface is needlessly limiting.

PS — I wrote the code to which John Zwinck linked.

Comment: Thank you very much ikegami for your solution! The pack/unpack functions is what I particularly needed.

Comment: @Eugene C., `."\0"` was missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right about $site holding the address of a string.  Here's some code that demonstrates the use of an output parameter with Perl's Win32 module:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=displaycode;node_id=890698

Comment: Thanks. Your link lead me to Perl's pack/unpack function which I looked into and is what I needed, until of course ikegami posted a solution. :)