# Parsing string into ARGV equivalent (Windows and Perl)

Tags: windows, perl, arguments

**Edit - Answer posted below**

I have a script that usually uses `@ARGV` arguments but in some cases it is invoked by another script (which I cannot modify) that instead only passes a config filename which among other things has the command line options that should have been passed directly.

Example:

```
Args=--test --pdf "C:\testing\my pdf files\test.pdf"
```

If possible I'd like a way to parse this string into an array that would be identical to `@ARGV`.

I have a workaround where I setup an external perl script that just echos `@ARGV`, and I invoke this script like below (standard boilerplate removed).

**echo-args.pl**

```
print join ("\n", @ARGV);
```

**test-echo-args.pl**

```
$my_args = '--test --pdf "C:\testing\my pdf files\test.pdf"';
@args = map { chomp ; $_ } `perl echo-args.pl $my_args`;
```

This seems inelegant but it works. Is there a better way without invoking a new process? I did try splitting and processing but there are some oddities on the command line e.g. `-a"b c"` becomes `'-ab c'` and `-a"b""` becomes `-ab"` and I'd rather not worry about edge cases but I know that'll bite me one day if I don't.

Comment: It looks like you need to use backticks or `system` to execute the command line, but what is the application that takes `Args` as parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is relevant to the question but test-echo-args.pl is an example of one such application. Assume the string $my_args comes from a file instead. How do we parse that string into an array?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is *the script*, what is *the other script*, and what `Args=--test ...` is an example of. It's clear to you only because you know the answer! If you're looking to write a program that will work with its command-line arguments, or read from `STDIN` if there are none, then you just need to write `if ( @ARGV ) { ... }` But I suspect that there's more to your question than that

Comment: Program A is designed to use `@ARGV` as is normal. Program B will call Program A but not with a proper command line. Instead it writes the string to a config file, and provides the config file name on the command line. Program A then needs to read this config file, find the argument string, and handle it. Since we already have code to parse `@ARGV`, we want to reuse it instead of reinventing the wheel. We will do this by splitting the string into an array. The examples above show this happening in a simplified way. Showing other details would have detracted from the point.

Comment: Tip: `while ($num > 0) { --$num; ... }` => `while ($num--) { ... }`. Or in this case, `for (1..$num) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami yes definitely it's a bad habit, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In unix systems, it's the shell that parses that shell command into strings. But in Windows, it's up to each application. I think this is normally done using the [`CommandLineToArgv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647232.aspx) system call (which you could call with the help of [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API)), but the spec is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) if you want to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this will be interesting to look into even if I can't use it. I'll give it a try and update later. I understand there are some differences from unix around wildcard expansion but was unable to find that spec when searching.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've edited to add some working code. I was about to give up until I saw your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529928/perl-win32api-and-pointers which had the very useful encode/decode/pack/unpack examples that I could use.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer - thanks ikegami!**

I've posted a working program below that uses `Win32::API` and `CommandLineToArgvW` from `shell32.dll` based on ikegami's advice. It is intentionally verbose in the hopes that it'll be more easy to follow for anyone like myself who is extremely rusty with C and pointer arithmetic.

Any tips are welcome, apart from the obvious simplifications :)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode     qw( encode decode );
use Win32::API qw( );
use Data::Dumper;

# create a test argument string, with some variations, and pack it
# apparently an empty string returns $^X which is documented so check before calling
my $arg_string = '--test 33 -3-t"  "es 33\t2 ';
my $packed_arg_string = encode('UTF-16le', $arg_string."\0");

# create a packed integer buffer for output
my $packed_argc_buf_ptr = pack('L', 0);

# create then call the function and get the result
my $func = Win32::API->new('shell32.dll', 'CommandLineToArgvW', 'PP', 'N')
   or die $^E;
my $ret = $func->Call($packed_arg_string, $packed_argc_buf_ptr);

# unpack to get the number of parsed arguments
my $argc = unpack('L', $packed_argc_buf_ptr);
print "We parsed $argc arguments\n";

# parse the return value to get the actual strings
my @argv = decode_LPWSTR_array($ret, $argc);
print Dumper \@argv;

# try not to leak memory
my $local_free = Win32::API->new('kernel32.dll', 'LocalFree', 'N', '')
    or die $^E; 
$local_free->Call($ret);

exit;

sub decode_LPWSTR_array {
    my ($ptr, $num) = @_;

    return undef if !$ptr;

    # $ptr is the memory location of the array of strings (i.e. more pointers)
    # $num is how many we need to get
    my @strings = ();

    for (1 .. $num) {
        # convert $ptr to a long, using that location read 4 bytes - this is the pointer to the next string
        my $string_location = unpack('P4', pack('L', $ptr));        
        # make it human readable
        my $readable_string_location = unpack('L', $string_location);       
        # decode the string and save it for later
        push(@strings, decode_LPCWSTR($readable_string_location));

        # our pointers are 32-bit
        $ptr += 4;      
    }
    return @strings;
}

# Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529928/perl-win32api-and-pointers
sub decode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $sW = '';
   for (;;) {
      my $chW = unpack('P2', pack('L', $ptr));
      last if $chW eq "\0\0";
      $sW .= $chW;
      $ptr += 2;
   }

   return decode('UTF-16le', $sW);   
}
```